# org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query

Tags: hibernate

I am executing query through criteria as-

```
 try {
        hsSession  = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        List<StdOrgUsersV> l = (List<StdOrgUsersV>) hsSession.createCriteria(StdOrgUsersV.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("partyType", ptype))
                .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("userId")).list();
        for(StdOrgUsersV souv:l){
            ar.add(souv.getUserId());
            ar.add(souv.getPartyFullName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The StdOrgUsersV class-

```
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Basic(optional = false)
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
private long id;
@Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
private long userId;
@Column(name = "ORG_UNIT_ID", nullable = false)
private long orgUnitId;
@Column(name = "INTERNAL_FLAG")
private Boolean internalFlag;
@Column(name = "PARENT_USER_ID")
private Long parentUserId;
@Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
private Long roleId;
@Column(name = "DEPARTMENT", length = 20)
private String department;
@Column(name = "USER_LOCATION_ID")
private Long userLocationId;
@Column(name = "SCREEN_WIDTH")
private Integer screenWidth;
@Column(name = "SCREEN_HEIGHT")
private Integer screenHeight;
@Column(name = "COMMENTS", length = 1000)
private String comments;
@Column(name = "REV_REF_ID")
private Long revRefId;
@Column(name = "REVISION_NO", nullable = false)
private int revisionNo;
@Column(name="ACTIVE_FLAG", nullable=false)
private boolean activeFlag;
@Column(name = "START_DATE", nullable = false, length = 23)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
@Column(name = "END_DATE", length = 23)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;
@Column(name = "CREATED_BY", nullable = false)
private long createdBy;
@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE", nullable = false, length = 23)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date creationDate;
@Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
private Long updatedBy;
@Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE", length = 23)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date updateDate;
@Column(name = "APPROVAL_LIMIT", precision = 18)
private BigDecimal approvalLimit;
@Column(name = "user_name", length = 50)
private String userName;
@Column(name = "role_name", length = 50)
private String roleName;
@Column(name = "Org_Type_Name", length = 100)
private String orgTypeName;
@Column(name = "ORG_UNIT_TYPE", length = 10)
private String orgUnitType;
@Column(name = "PARTY_TYPE", length = 20)
private String partyType;
@Column(name = "ORG_UNIT_NAME", length = 50)
private String orgUnitName;
@Column(name = "Dept_Name", length = 100)
private String deptName;
@Column(name = "parent_party_name", length = 100)
private String parentPartyName;
@Column(name = "Party_id")
private Long partyId;
@Column(name = "Party_Full_Name", length = 100)
private String partyFullName;
@Column(name = "LOCATION_NAME", length = 50)
private String locationName;
@Column(name = "Loc_Type_Name", length = 100)
private String locTypeName;
@Column(name = "LOCATION_TYPE", length = 20)
private String locationType;
@Column(name = "parent1_id")
private Long parent1Id;
@Column(name = "parent1_loc_name", length = 50)
private String parent1LocName;
@Column(name = "parent1_loc_type", length = 20)
private String parent1LocType;
@Column(name = "parent2_id")
private Long parent2Id;
@Column(name = "parent2_loc_name", length = 50)
private String parent2LocName;
@Column(name = "parent2_loc_type", length = 20)
private String parent2LocType;
@Column(name = "parent3_id")
private Long parent3Id;
@Column(name = "parent3_loc_name", length = 50)
private String parent3LocName;
@Column(name = "parent3_loc_type", length = 20)
private String parent3LocType;
@Column(name = "parent4_id")
private Long parent4Id;
@Column(name = "parent4_loc_name", length = 50)
private String parent4LocName;
@Column(name = "parent4_loc_type", length = 20)
private String parent4LocType;
@Column(name = "parent5_id")
private Long parent5Id;
@Column(name = "parent5_loc_name", length = 50)
private String parent5LocName;
@Column(name = "parent5_loc_type", length = 20)
private String parent5LocType;
@Column(name = "parent_role_id")
private Long parentRoleId;
@Column(name = "Parent_Role_Name", length = 50)
private String parentRoleName;
@Column(name = "ORG_ADDRESS", length = 200)
private String orgAddress;
@Column(name = "parent1_role_id")
private Long parent1RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent1_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent1RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent2_role_id")
private Long parent2RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent2_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent2RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent3_role_id")
private Long parent3RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent3_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent3RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent4_role_id")
private Long parent4RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent4_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent4RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent5_role_id")
private Long parent5RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent5_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent5RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent6_role_id")
private Long parent6RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent6_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent6RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent7_role_id")
private Long parent7RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent7_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent7RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent8_role_id")
private Long parent8RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent8_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent8RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent9_role_id")
private Long parent9RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent9_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent9RoleName;
@Column(name = "parent10_role_id")
private Long parent10RoleId;
@Column(name = "parent10_role_name", length = 50)
private String parent10RoleName;
@Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 50)
private String email;
@Column(name = "PARTY_TITLE", length = 10)
private String partyTitle;
@Column(name = "PARTY_NAME", length = 100)
private String partyName;
@Column(name = "CONTACT_NO", length = 15)
private String contactNo;
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE1", length = 200)
private String addressLine1;
@Column(name = "CITY", length = 20)
private String city;
@Column(name = "STATE", length = 20)
private String state;
@Column(name = "LOCATION_ID")
private Long locationId;
@Column(name = "PARTY_START_DATE", length = 23)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date partyStartDate;
@Column(name = "USER_GROUP_ID")
private Long userGroupId;
@Column(name = "user_group_name", length = 50)
private String userGroupName;

gettrs and setters....
```

I have checked the query created by hibernate in Sql server and that is working fine but on executing the criteria above im getting the following exception-

```
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID11_0_, this_.USER_ID as USER2_11_0_, this_.ORG_UNIT_ID as ORG3_11_0_, this_.INTERNAL_FLAG as INTERNAL4_11_0_, this_.PARENT_USER_ID as PARENT5_11_0_, this_.ROLE_ID as ROLE6_11_0_, this_.DEPARTMENT as DEPARTMENT11_0_, this_.USER_LOCATION_ID as USER8_11_0_, this_.SCREEN_WIDTH as SCREEN9_11_0_, this_.SCREEN_HEIGHT as SCREEN10_11_0_, this_.COMMENTS as COMMENTS11_0_, this_.REV_REF_ID as REV12_11_0_, this_.REVISION_NO as REVISION13_11_0_, this_.ACTIVE_FLAG as ACTIVE14_11_0_, this_.START_DATE as START15_11_0_, this_.END_DATE as END16_11_0_, this_.CREATED_BY as CREATED17_11_0_, this_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION18_11_0_, this_.UPDATED_BY as UPDATED19_11_0_, this_.UPDATE_DATE as UPDATE20_11_0_, this_.APPROVAL_LIMIT as APPROVAL21_11_0_, this_.user_name as user22_11_0_, this_.role_name as role23_11_0_, this_.Org_Type_Name as Org24_11_0_, this_.ORG_UNIT_TYPE as ORG25_11_0_, this_.PARTY_TYPE as PARTY26_11_0_, this_.ORG_UNIT_NAME as ORG27_11_0_, this_.Dept_Name as Dept28_11_0_, this_.parent_party_name as parent29_11_0_, this_.Party_id as Party30_11_0_, this_.Party_Full_Name as Party31_11_0_, this_.LOCATION_NAME as LOCATION32_11_0_, this_.Loc_Type_Name as Loc33_11_0_, this_.LOCATION_TYPE as LOCATION34_11_0_, this_.parent1_id as parent35_11_0_, this_.parent1_loc_name as parent36_11_0_, this_.parent1_loc_type as parent37_11_0_, this_.parent2_id as parent38_11_0_, this_.parent2_loc_name as parent39_11_0_, this_.parent2_loc_type as parent40_11_0_, this_.parent3_id as parent41_11_0_, this_.parent3_loc_name as parent42_11_0_, this_.parent3_loc_type as parent43_11_0_, this_.parent4_id as parent44_11_0_, this_.parent4_loc_name as parent45_11_0_, this_.parent4_loc_type as parent46_11_0_, this_.parent5_id as parent47_11_0_, this_.parent5_loc_name as parent48_11_0_, this_.parent5_loc_type as parent49_11_0_, this_.parent_role_id as parent50_11_0_, this_.Parent_Role_Name as Parent51_11_0_, this_.ORG_ADDRESS as ORG52_11_0_, this_.parent1_role_id as parent53_11_0_, this_.parent1_role_name as parent54_11_0_, this_.parent2_role_id as parent55_11_0_, this_.parent2_role_name as parent56_11_0_, this_.parent3_role_id as parent57_11_0_, this_.parent3_role_name as parent58_11_0_, this_.parent4_role_id as parent59_11_0_, this_.parent4_role_name as parent60_11_0_, this_.parent5_role_id as parent61_11_0_, this_.parent5_role_name as parent62_11_0_, this_.parent6_role_id as parent63_11_0_, this_.parent6_role_name as parent64_11_0_, this_.parent7_role_id as parent65_11_0_, this_.parent7_role_name as parent66_11_0_, this_.parent8_role_id as parent67_11_0_, this_.parent8_role_name as parent68_11_0_, this_.parent9_role_id as parent69_11_0_, this_.parent9_role_name as parent70_11_0_, this_.parent10_role_id as parent71_11_0_, this_.parent10_role_name as parent72_11_0_, this_.EMAIL as EMAIL11_0_, this_.PARTY_TITLE as PARTY74_11_0_, this_.PARTY_NAME as PARTY75_11_0_, this_.CONTACT_NO as CONTACT76_11_0_, this_.ADDRESS_LINE1 as ADDRESS77_11_0_, this_.CITY as CITY11_0_, this_.STATE as STATE11_0_, this_.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION80_11_0_, this_.PARTY_START_DATE as PARTY81_11_0_, this_.USER_GROUP_ID as USER82_11_0_, this_.user_group_name as user83_11_0_ from STD_ORG_USERS_V this_ where this_.PARTY_TYPE=?
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID11_0_, this_.USER_ID as USER2_11_0_, this_.ORG_UNIT_ID as ORG3_11_0_, this_.INTERNAL_FLAG as INTERNAL4_11_0_, this_.PARENT_USER_ID as PARENT5_11_0_, this_.ROLE_ID as ROLE6_11_0_, this_.DEPARTMENT as DEPARTMENT11_0_, this_.USER_LOCATION_ID as USER8_11_0_, this_.SCREEN_WIDTH as SCREEN9_11_0_, this_.SCREEN_HEIGHT as SCREEN10_11_0_, this_.COMMENTS as COMMENTS11_0_, this_.REV_REF_ID as REV12_11_0_, this_.REVISION_NO as REVISION13_11_0_, this_.ACTIVE_FLAG as ACTIVE14_11_0_, this_.START_DATE as START15_11_0_, this_.END_DATE as END16_11_0_, this_.CREATED_BY as CREATED17_11_0_, this_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION18_11_0_, this_.UPDATED_BY as UPDATED19_11_0_, this_.UPDATE_DATE as UPDATE20_11_0_, this_.APPROVAL_LIMIT as APPROVAL21_11_0_, this_.user_name as user22_11_0_, this_.role_name as role23_11_0_, this_.Org_Type_Name as Org24_11_0_, this_.ORG_UNIT_TYPE as ORG25_11_0_, this_.PARTY_TYPE as PARTY26_11_0_, this_.ORG_UNIT_NAME as ORG27_11_0_, this_.Dept_Name as Dept28_11_0_, this_.parent_party_name as parent29_11_0_, this_.Party_id as Party30_11_0_, this_.Party_Full_Name as Party31_11_0_, this_.LOCATION_NAME as LOCATION32_11_0_, this_.Loc_Type_Name as Loc33_11_0_, this_.LOCATION_TYPE as LOCATION34_11_0_, this_.parent1_id as parent35_11_0_, this_.parent1_loc_name as parent36_11_0_, this_.parent1_loc_type as parent37_11_0_, this_.parent2_id as parent38_11_0_, this_.parent2_loc_name as parent39_11_0_, this_.parent2_loc_type as parent40_11_0_, this_.parent3_id as parent41_11_0_, this_.parent3_loc_name as parent42_11_0_, this_.parent3_loc_type as parent43_11_0_, this_.parent4_id as parent44_11_0_, this_.parent4_loc_name as parent45_11_0_, this_.parent4_loc_type as parent46_11_0_, this_.parent5_id as parent47_11_0_, this_.parent5_loc_name as parent48_11_0_, this_.parent5_loc_type as parent49_11_0_, this_.parent_role_id as parent50_11_0_, this_.Parent_Role_Name as Parent51_11_0_, this_.ORG_ADDRESS as ORG52_11_0_, this_.parent1_role_id as parent53_11_0_, this_.parent1_role_name as parent54_11_0_, this_.parent2_role_id as parent55_11_0_, this_.parent2_role_name as parent56_11_0_, this_.parent3_role_id as parent57_11_0_, this_.parent3_role_name as parent58_11_0_, this_.parent4_role_id as parent59_11_0_, this_.parent4_role_name as parent60_11_0_, this_.parent5_role_id as parent61_11_0_, this_.parent5_role_name as parent62_11_0_, this_.parent6_role_id as parent63_11_0_, this_.parent6_role_name as parent64_11_0_, this_.parent7_role_id as parent65_11_0_, this_.parent7_role_name as parent66_11_0_, this_.parent8_role_id as parent67_11_0_, this_.parent8_role_name as parent68_11_0_, this_.parent9_role_id as parent69_11_0_, this_.parent9_role_name as parent70_11_0_, this_.parent10_role_id as parent71_11_0_, this_.parent10_role_name as parent72_11_0_, this_.EMAIL as EMAIL11_0_, this_.PARTY_TITLE as PARTY74_11_0_, this_.PARTY_NAME as PARTY75_11_0_, this_.CONTACT_NO as CONTACT76_11_0_, this_.ADDRESS_LINE1 as ADDRESS77_11_0_, this_.CITY as CITY11_0_, this_.STATE as STATE11_0_, this_.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION80_11_0_, this_.PARTY_START_DATE as PARTY81_11_0_, this_.USER_GROUP_ID as USER82_11_0_, this_.user_group_name as user83_11_0_ from STD_ORG_USERS_V this_ where this_.PARTY_TYPE=?
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:77)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2214)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:305)
at WF.workflow.getUsersVikas(workflow.java:547)
at org.apache.jsp.MARICON.ParentUser_jsp._jspService(ParentUser_jsp.java:149)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The value supplied cannot be converted to BIGINT.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support.convert(Support.java:653)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.getLong(JtdsResultSet.java:645)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.getLong(JtdsResultSet.java:972)
at org.hibernate.type.LongType.get(LongType.java:28)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:113)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:102)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2046)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1371)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1299)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1197)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:568)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:689)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
... 30 more
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to verify the types of the columns against the ones you have declared in the bean as it seems there is a type conversion issue.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The value supplied cannot be converted to BIGINT.
```

I have noticed that some of the fields are having `long`, some are `Long`; which should be OK. But it is nice to use either primitives or references; but not a mix.

As a quick check, I suggest you to check whether `retrieving all` works without any issue.

```
hsSession.createQuery("from StdOrgUsersV").list()
```

If above query also results in the same issue, then it is obviously a data type issue; not due to the `Criteria`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, i have also compared all the columns, datatypes and even their length with the bean attributes and types as well, everything is fine but still having the same issue. Is there any issue of column APPROVAL_LIMIT? it is of numeric(18,2) type in db.

Comment: So just to get a confirmation; did 'get all' work? Or is that also failing?

Comment: Checking with particular attributes i got the problem with `parent1RoleId` which is of **Long** type in bean and related column `parent1_role_id` which is of **bigint** type in db. Im not getting what's wrong with that. I have also checked the attribute with `long` but still same issue.

Comment: Oki... so what is the status of the below query? 

hsSession.createQuery("from StdOrgUsersV").list()

Comment: Its throwing the same attached exception.

Comment: Oki.. so it means there is a problem only with your mappings, not with the query. I would suggest you to trim this large bean into few fields (like one long, one BigDecimal). Then you can easily find the issue.